# How to change Opera's proxy settings from Watir-Webdriver?

Tags: ruby, proxy, opera, mechanize, watir-webdriver

(This question is loosely related to [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8597403/watir-webdriver-change-proxy-while-keeping-browser-open/8612687#8612687))

Hello there.

I have been using Watir-Webdriver with Mozilla FireFox for a week now, and I am quite pleased with it. However, since I am making a test wich tries to connect to some websites multiple times using different proxies, I found that using FireFox was extremely slow. Firefox's starting time is (at least on my computer) about 15 seconds(if you're lucky) so I am looking to find something to speed the thing up. This made me look into other browsers and their start up times. It seems Opera is quite fast. However, since it is 'new' in Selenium Webdriver and thus also in Watir-webdriver there is not much documentation about it.

Enough talking, time for the question:

**How can I, using watir-webdriver(or Selenium-webdriver directly), change the proxy that Opera uses for connections?**

Comment: Did you see my answer to your other proxy server question suggesting to use Mechanize? If speed is a concern, you would be 1000's times faster with that and proxy settings are easily controllable.

Comment: I agree, if the entire intent is just to see if you can get a response from the webserver, and you do not need to 'see' the site in a browser much less interact with it, then doing this at the browser level is the wrong solution to the problem.  Use a headless approach with Mechanize or a similar gem (capybara? not sure if it has easy proxy settings).   

 Right tool for the job son, ah say use the right tool for the job. </foghorn>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not quite sure I understand the use case, but as a hack/workaround you can change any Opera setting from OperaWatir by loading opera:config and running JS in it to set preferences. In other words,

```
browser.goto('opera:config')
browser.execute_script( 'opera.setPreference("Proxy", "HTTP Server", "127.0.0.1:8888")' )
browser.execute_script( 'opera.setPreference("Proxy", "Use HTTP", "1")' )
```

should work without restart or anything. The opera:config page itself shows you the options you can set.

Comment: And just a couple of hours after posting that solution, I learnt that there will be a proper syntax for this in the future: browser.preferences.proxy.use_http=1 - so you may have to start using that at some point..